# Return Mutable Dictionary after async call

Tags: ios

Am new to iOS programming, am trying to build a small app which communicates with another server to retreive XML and parse it. Right now I have implemented NSXML parser delegates in the same View Controller, I want to write a separate class which would accept the XML path, parse it and return meaningful data.

So in view controller I have this

```
// On Foo Button Click
XMLParser* xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
// XMLParser would be my class file which has a method to parse XML
xmlParser.readXMLFromPath(pathToXML);
```

In the XMLParser class file:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary*) readXMLFromPath: (NSString* pathToXML) {
  NSMutableDictionary* resultSet;
  // Alloc NSXMLParser and implement its delegate methods
  // resultSet would now hold the needed Data
}
```

So now how should I return back `resultSet` back to the viewController ?

Comment: Usually the idea here is to send a call back method to your async process that when it's done it calls to update the UI or perform another task or whatever

Comment: You should learn about protocols

Answer (score 0):

Have the client of your XML parser pass in a block to execute when the results are ready instead of returning them immediately.  You could also have the client pass in a separate errorBlock as well for when things go wrong.

```
- (void)readXMLFromPathWithSuccessBlock:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *results))successBlock;
 {
  // Alloc NSXMLParser and implement its delegate methods
  // Save successBlock in a property
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
  // Call success block and pass results to the client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subclass of NSOperation that I use to do all my xml parsing on an NSOperationQueue:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GDBaseParser.h"

@class ParseXMLOperation;

@protocol ParseXMLCallbackDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)parseOperationComplete:(ParseXMLOperation *)completedOperation;

@end

@interface ParseXMLOperation : NSOperation 
{
    GDBaseParser *xmlParserDelegate;
    NSData *dataToParse;
    id <ParseXMLCallbackDelegate> callbackDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)GDBaseParser *xmlParserDelegate;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSData *dataToParse;
@property(nonatomic,strong)id <ParseXMLCallbackDelegate> callbackDelegate;
-(id)initWithParser:(GDBaseParser *)inParserDelegate;
@end


@implementation ParseXMLOperation

@synthesize xmlParserDelegate, dataToParse, callbackDelegate;

-(id)initWithParser:(GDBaseParser *)inParserDelegate
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self != nil )
    {
        self.xmlParserDelegate = inParserDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {

        NSXMLParser *parser  = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataToParse];
        xmlParserDelegate.currentContext = localContext;
        [parser setDelegate:xmlParserDelegate];
        [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [parser parse];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendOperationComplete) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    }


}


-(void)sendOperationComplete
{
    if( callbackDelegate != nil && [callbackDelegate     respondsToSelector:@selector(parseOperationComplete:)] )
    {
        [callbackDelegate parseOperationComplete:self];
    }
}
```

I then can set up the operation and add it to the queue by doing this:

```
         MyParser *parserDelegate = [[MyParser alloc] init];
ParseXMLOperation *parseOperation = [[ParseXMLOperation alloc]   initWithParser:parserDelegate];
         parseOperation.dataToParse = parseData;
         parseOperation.completionBlock = ^{
             localOperation.messageHeaderDict = parserDelegate.messageHeaders;
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 //notify your UI that you are done with your parsing
             });

         };
         [self.xmlParsingQueue addOperation:parseOperation];
```